# Python: How to split a sentence in an ideal way in more or less equal pieces

Tags: python, string

I am trying to write a function that splits a sentence in n lines. My goal is to get it as evenly distributed as possible but my results are that either the first line or the last line is way too long compared to the other lines.

Example:

"Who has eaten the fresh brownies?" split in 4 lines.

ideal:

```
Who has
eaten
the fresh
brownies
```

I get:

```
Who has eaten
the fresh
brownies
```

(3 lines, first too long)

or

```
who has
eaten the
fresh brownies
```

(3 lines not 4)

or

```
who has 
eaten
the
fresh brownies
```

(last line too long)

It seems to be a really hard problem to tackle. I only want to break the sentence on spaces. So start is easy:

```
words = sentence.split()
total_words = len(words)
character_count = len(sentence)
```

From there I have created so much garbage that I am about to start fresh. Any advice? Should work with all kind of different sentences, very short ones and longer ones and also for different amount of lines...

Comment: Your expected output needs clarification _because_ it is unclear how many characters or words should be allowed on each line.

Comment: You can consider average of the words as well as average of the words length. And based on that you can make your condition

Comment: why is "Who has \n eaten \n the fresh \n brownies" ideal instead of "Who has \n eaten the \n fresh \n brownies" ?

Comment: What if the sentence isn't appropriate for splitting across 4 lines? e.g., if there are only 3 words?

Comment: What should be done with "Cats love some dead fish"

Comment: This is probably suitable for [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). TeX uses a similar (though more complicated) algorithm to decide where to insert line breaks in a paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt to solve the problem. First of all, it stores the ideal length of each line, which is `len(sentence)/num_lines`. However, it is unlikely that a space happens to lie exactly on this index. So the function searches for the closest space to that index with `split_at = min(find_spaces(temp_sentence), key=lambda x: abs(x-avg_len))` and uses this as your split index.

```
def split_sentence(sentence, num_lines):
    def find_spaces(string): # function that returns the index of spaces in a string
        return [i for i, letter in enumerate(string) if letter == ' ']

    avg_len = len(sentence)/num_lines # the ideal length of a line

    temp_sentence = sentence
    solution = ''
    for _ in range(num_lines-1):
        split_at = min(find_spaces(temp_sentence), key=lambda x: abs(x-avg_len)) # find the closest space to ideal line length
        solution+= '\n' + temp_sentence[:split_at] # update solution
        temp_sentence = temp_sentence[split_at+1:] # +1 is to ignore the space
    solution+= '\n' + temp_sentence # add the last bit of the string
    return solution

sentence = 'Who has eaten the fresh brownies?'
num_lines = 4
print(split_sentence(sentence, num_lines))
```

This code returns:

```
Who has
eaten the
fresh
brownies?
```

It seems to work quite well with other strings too:
`I am trying to write a function that splits a sentence in n lines.`
returns:

```
I am trying to
write a function
that splits a
sentence in n lines.
```

Note that the function will return an error if the number of words is less than the number of lines. I hope this is good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you want but I am reminded of my ebook way of justifying text to fit the whole page.

`Who has eaten the fresh brownies?`

- Have a limit of characters, let's say 12.
- Grab the first word and count the characters `Who` = 3 (total 3)
- Grab the second word and count the characters `has` = 3 (total 6)
- Grab the third word and count the characters `eaten` = 5 (total 11)
- Grab the fourth word and count the characters `the` = 3 (total 4)
- This one doesn't fit, take it out and create a line with what you have `Who has eaten`
- Start the second line with the word that didn't fit `the` = 3 (total 3)
- Grab the second word and count the characters `fresh` = 5 (total 8)
- Grab the third word and count the characters `brownies?` = 9 (total 17)
- This one doesn't fit, take it out and create a line with what you have `the fresh`
- Start the third line with the word that didn't fit `brownies?` = 9 (total 9)

So you end up with
`Who has eaten`
`the fresh`
`brownies?`

Each time you get the current character count you could add 1 to account for spaces, or at the end you could add as many spaces as necessary to pad the strings to the same character limit (12)

`Who has eaten`
`the    fresh`
`brownies?`

It's not perfect since the first line has 13 chars, but just an idea.